# Getting field name and values and storing it in a map

Tags: java

This is my code for getting field values and annotation values, I placed the values into a map, however problem is there is a `$this` that is in the map.

```
Map doc = null;
        String kind = null;
        Class classObj = obj.getClass();
        Annotation[] annotations = classObj.getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                Entity entityAnnotation = (Entity)annotation; 
                kind = entityAnnotation.name();
                if (entityAnnotation != null){
                        if (doc == null){
                            doc = new LinkedHashMap();
                        }
                        Field[] fields = classObj.getDeclaredFields();
                        for (Field field : fields){
                                annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                                String value = null;
                                String fieldName = field.getName();
                                try {
                                        boolean access = field.isAccessible();
                                        field.setAccessible(true);
                                        Object fieldValue = field.get(obj); 
                                        doc.put(fieldName, fieldValue);
                                        field.setAccessible(access);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }                               
                                // Process fields with annotation
                                for(Annotation fieldAnnotation : annotations){
                                    if (annotation instanceof Id){
                                        Id idAnnotation = (Id) fieldAnnotation;
                                        log.info("Field name="+fieldName+" "+ value + " Annotation value: " + idAnnotation.value()); 
                                        doc.put("_id", value);
                                    }                                   
                                }
                        }                               
                }
        }
```

Test output:

```
Key=id value=id1
Key=name value=Eli
Key=age value=25
Key=this$0 value=org.goo.AnnotationTest@7f5227
```

Comment: Could you please indent you code with four spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `this$0` is the reference to the outer class.

If you want to avoid this, make the class `static`.  IMHO you should make nested class static where possible, partly for performance, but mostly for clarity.  If this is not an option, you can ignore that field explicitly.

BTW: If you create a field called `this$0` it will use the field `this$$0` or `this$$$0` or `this$$$$0` etc instead.

Comment: How can I avoid that being stored in the map, I need the map to have the field values only (declared in the class)

Comment: Make the class static and it won't have the field. If you can't do that add `if(!field.getName().equals("this$0"))`

Comment: the 'obj' which its fields are process can be any Object. As I am building a library that a user can create any pass and pass it into the method that will parse the field values and annotation values

Comment: In that case you can exclude it by name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to get class variable and store in Map.
    Field[] fields = YourClassName.class.getFields();

Comment: What if the I just pass an Object in which it would not know the class name. I just get the "Object"

Comment: You can see this example. Object belongs to any class. you never need to know just use as in the example below.                                 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Object obj = new YourClass();
  java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
  System.out.println("Before loop");
  for(java.lang.reflect.Field field:fields)
  {
   System.out.println(field.getName());
  }
 }